# Can't run syncdb on Google CloudSQL OperationalError 1045 Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' using password: NO

Tags: python, mysql, django, google-app-engine, python-2.7

Based on the following [google documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/django) and [tutorials](http://howto.pui.ch/post/39245389801/tutorial-django-on-appengine-using-google-cloud-sql) I have the following setup.

I have never had google prompt me for the oauth token url. As it should per their documentation. I am not sure what is going wrong.
May be some one could try the `--traceback` option with `-v 3` on syncdb and show me what paths and libraries are being called when you use syncdb.
`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth.`

This is the error I get trying to connect using syncdb

```
$ SETTINGS_MODE='prod' python manage.py  syncdb -v 3 --traceback  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/home/user/bin/lib/google_appengine/lib/django-1.5/django/core/management/base.py", line 222, in run_from_argv  
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)  
  File "/home/user/bin/lib/google_appengine/lib/django-1.5/django/core/management/base.py", line 255, in execute  
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)  
  File "/home/user/bin/lib/google_appengine/lib/django-1.5/django/core/management/base.py", line 385, in handle  
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)  
  File "/home/user/bin/lib/google_appengine/lib/django-1.5/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 56, in handle_noargs  
    cursor = connection.cursor()  
  File "/home/user/bin/lib/google_appengine/lib/django-1.5/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 324, in cursor  
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())  
  File "/home/user/bin/lib/google_appengine/lib/django-1.5/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 406, in _cursor  
    self.connection = Database.connect(**kwargs)  
  File "/home/user/projects/my-app/src/my-app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect  
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)  
  File "/home/user/projects/my-app/src/my-app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 193, in __init__  
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)  
OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")
```

When I tried using the specific versions of django the comes with GAE and setting the PATH using the setting that manage.py provides. I get exactly the same error.

```
SETTINGS_MODE='prod' python ../lib/google_appengine/lib/django-1.5/django/bin/django- admin.py  syncdb -v 3 --traceback --settings=opexdash.settings --pythonpath=.
```

Yet I can get using dbshell with out any issues.

```
$ SETTINGS_MODE='prod' python manage.py dbshell  
Reading table information for completion of table and column names  
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A  

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.  
Your MySQL connection id is 54  
Server version: 5.5.39 (Google)  

Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.  

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its  
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective  
owners.  

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.  

mysql> select @@hostname;  
+------------+  
| @@hostname |  
+------------+  
| localhost  |  
+------------+  
1 row in set (0.40 sec)  

mysql> select database();  
+------------+  
| database() |  
+------------+  
| my_db      |  
+------------+  
1 row in set (0.32 sec)
```

Here are the additional settings I am using as per the documentation.

```
if os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE', '').startswith('Google App Engine'):  
    # Running on production App Engine, so use a Google Cloud SQL database.  
    DATABASES = {  
        'default': {  
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',  
            'HOST': '/cloudsql/nth-hybrid-672:beta-dash02',  
            'NAME': 'my-app',  
            'USER': 'root',  
        }  
    }  
elif os.getenv('SETTINGS_MODE') == 'prod':  
    # Running in development, but want to access the Google Cloud SQL instance  
    # in production.  
    DATABASES = {  
        'default': {  
            #'ENGINE': 'google.appengine.ext.django.backends.rdbms',  
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',  
            'INSTANCE': 'your-project-id:your-instance-name',  
            'NAME': 'my-app',  
            'USER': 'root',  
            #'HOST': '173.100.100.100',  I can synkdb using it this way with a password set, ip address has been changed for this public forum
            #'PASSWORD' : ''  
        }  
    }  
else:  
    # Running in development, so use a local MySQL database.  
    DATABASES = {  
        'default': {  
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',  
            'NAME': 'gae',  
            'USER': 'gae',  
            'PASSWORD': 'gae',  
        }  
    }
```

I think the problem is most likely down to my paths that environmental setup. 
But I expect that when I use the full path for manage in the GAE/lib directory that
it should work.

```
$PATH
/home/user/projects/my-app/src/my-app/bin:   
/usr/local/sbin:  
/usr/local/bin:  
/usr/sbin:  
/usr/bin:   
/sbin:  
/bin:  
/usr/games:  
/usr/local/games:  
/usr/lib/jvm/default-java:  
/usr/share/javadb/bin:  
/home/user/bin:  
/home/user/bin/lib/google_appengine/:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need oauth, you are connecting to the database as though it is a normal remote MySQL instance; hence you need

```
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',  
'NAME': 'my-app',  # your DB name
'USER': 'root',  
'HOST': '173.xxx.xxx.xxx',  # your instance's IP address
'PASSWORD' : 'your-root-password-here',
```

(Assuming you have allowed your own IP to connect to the instance.) You can also set up the connection to go over SSL.

Google's docs are out of date, but [this post comes from a Google Cloud SQL engineer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20509968) and asserts that the recommended way to connect is to treat the MySQL instance as a normal remote server.

Comment: As per your post, here is the link to google dev help that explains this. https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/external