# Connection Timing Out When Accessing Gcloud MySQL from Python

Tags: python, mysql, gcloud, pymysql

I have a python application where I'm trying to access a MySQL database on Google's cloud service.

I've been following this [set up guide](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#python) for connecting via an external application (Python) and I am using the pymysql package. I'm attempting to connect via the proxy and have already authenticated my connection via gcloud auth log in from the console.

As of now, I CAN access the database via the console, but I need to be able to make queries from my python script to build it out. When I try running it as is, I get the following error:
OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '34.86.47.192' (timed out)")

Here's the function I'm using, with security sensitive info starred out:

```
def uploadData():
    # cd to the directory with the MySQL exe
    os.chdir('C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\bin')  
    # Invoke the proxy 
    subprocess.call('start cloud_sql_proxy_x64.exe -instances=trans-cosine-289719:us-east4:compuweather', shell=True)
    # Create connection    
    # I have also tried host = '127.0.0.1' for localhost here
    conn = pymysql.connect(host='34.86.47.192',
                                 user='root',
                                 password='*******',
                                 db='gribdata')
    try:
        c = conn.cursor()
        # Use the right databse
        db_query = 'use gribdata'
        c.execute(db_query)
        query = 'SELECT * FROM clients'
        c.execute(query)
        result = c.fetchall()
        print(result)
    except Error as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        conn.close()
```

Comment: How have you authorized with GCP? Do you have a service account set with the proper permissions to run the proxy and connect to Cloud SQL?

Comment: Easiest way to do this btw, is to pass it to the cloud_sql_proxy with the `-credential_file` parameter (it takes the path to the service account json file). That service account needs to have the Cloud SQL Client role in order to be able to talk to the Cloud SQL instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, this one's pretty limited in documentation, but what you want to do is run it from it's hosted IP and configure access to your external IP address on your server. So you want use that IP (34.xxx.xxx.xxx) rather than the loopback 127 local host IP.

To get it to work, you want to go to your connections tab and add a new connection within Gcloud. Make sure the public address box is checked, the IP is correct, and you save once done.

[image]

There's some excellent details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508494/why-does-manage-py-syncdb-fail-to-connect-to-google-cloud-sql-database/20509968#20509968) from some Gcloud engineers. Looks like some of the source documentation is outdated and this is the way to connect now.

Comment: Wait... just so I understand, now you've authorized your app's IP address (in this case, 34.xxx.xxx.xxx) and are connecting to it directly from your application? Just be aware, this means you are NOT using the proxy anymore, right? And if that's the case, if you're not using SSL, this means you're connecting unencrypted to your database (unless you're doing other stuff like VPN or something). Just be aware that you're sending unencrypted data to your database unless I'm missing another step you're doing?

Comment: I am using SSL, so it isn't a completely unencrypted connection. That's good to know that it isn't technically using the proxy, but for my purposes it doesn't really matter I just need to be able to remotely access the database, and this solution accomplishes that

Answer (score 1):

First of all, confirm that the Cloud SQL proxy is indeed installed in the directory that you are expecting it to be. The Cloud SQL proxy is not part of MySQL Server, hence you should not find it in `C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\bin`, at least by default. Instead, the Cloud SQL proxy is a tool provided by Google and is just an `.exe` file that can be stored in any directory you wish. For instructions on how to download the Proxy you can check the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#install)

The Cloud SQL proxy creates a secure link between the Cloud SQL instance and your machine. what it does is forward a local port in your machine to the Cloud SQL instance. Thus, the host IP that you should use if you are using the proxy is `127.0.0.1`

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1',
                             user='root',
                             password='*******',
                             db='gribdata')
```

When starting the Cloud SQL Proxy with TCP socket, you should add the port to which you want to forward Cloud SQL's traffic at the end of the start command `=tcp:3306`

```
subprocess.call('start cloud_sql_proxy_x64.exe -instances=trans-cosine-289719:us-east4:compuweather=tcp:3306', shell=True)
```

Comment: Let me know if it helps. 
I am not familiar with the effects that starting a process within Python can have on this, so if it doesn't work I will investigate further

Comment: Yeah I manually moved it to that directory myself since it relies upon the MySQL executable. I've tried using the loopback address, and while what you're suggesting matches Google's documentation, I can't seem to get it to work, I get the same time out error in Python. It does work fine in the proxy itself though

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to connect CloudSQL from the console? Once you connected, you should get a message in the console displaying "Listening on 127.0.0.1:3306".Your connection command should be

"cloud_sql_proxy_x64.exe -instances=trans-cosine-289719:us-east4:compuweather=tcp:3306"

Try to connect cloud proxy from the console and try to create a connection with pymysql. Use "127.0.0.1".

Comment: When I run it separately, it just says "using project cosine..." and then closes. Meanwhile, running with the localhost IP gives access denied